# How is l4j ending up on my classpath after maven package?

Tags: maven, log4j, slf4j, dropwizard

I have a rest service running on dropwizard. Dropwizard requires slf4j to be configured with logback. When launching this service directly from my maven project in eclipse, the service starts up with the proper logback binding. When I do a maven package with the maven shade plugin, however, the resulting jar is still pulling log4j onto the classpath, which is resulting in slf4j choosing  org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory instead of the logback binding.

I have made sure to exclude every transitive instance of log4j in my pom, as well as slf4j-log4j12 (mvn dependency:tree shows neither of these in my hierarchy), yet somehow it still always shows up in my uber jar after running mvn clean package.

How can I figure out what is causing log4j to always exist on my classpath?

Comment: Post `mvn dependency:tree`. Some dependencies must still bring it transitively.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml file ? As @Tunaki suggested you run mvn dependency:tree command and double check the output.